# Making multiple GUIs at once, but it takes ages! How can I do it faster

Tags: user-interface, autohotkey

I am loading 15 GUIs at once. But it takes ages literally. It also takes quite time when I read another data and applied to those GUIs. Hope to get any hints so that I will be able to do by my own. Thanks!

```
;Gui, Add, Button,x-20 y-20 gButton +default
Gui -Caption +LastFound +AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow
Gui, Margin, 0, 0
Gui, Font,s8 cBlack



Loop,15
{
    AIndex:=A_Index-1
    X:=Mod(AIndex,29)*37+20
    Y:=(Floor(AIndex/29))*130+30
    Gui,Add,Progress,x%X% y%y% h100 w25 cBlue VerticalProgress_Value_%A_Index%,50
    x:=x-7
    y:=y+100
    Gui,Add,Button,x%x% y%y% W40 vProgress_Title_%A_Index% gProgress_Execute
    x:=x+6
    y:=y-110
    Gui,Add,Text,x%x% y%y% W40 vProgress_Percent_%A_Index%
}

Mask := "Yellow"
Gui,Color, Yellow
;WinSet, TransColor, %Mask%
Gui,-dpiscale 
Gui,Show, x0 y0 h1100

return
```

Comment: I just ran this script, and no wait for it to show up. It must something else slowing your script. Please post more of the code.

Comment: Cheers man. I just found that there was clipwait in another part of the script. Modified successfully

Comment: Ahhh okay, glad things worked out :)

Comment: You should delete the question, or provide your own answer and accept it.